# How do I write a selector for DOM at Javascript vs. puppeteer $x eveluation selector?

Tags: javascript, selector, puppeteer

I have used puppeteer (More at is at: YT: [Puppeteer Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzZ3YOUhCxo) [WebSite](https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-build-a-web-scraper-using-puppeteer-and-node-js/?fbclid=IwAR3sDlQI432884vGTTryIFmGRoaCDqz8lffB7l2-ydhzy5Vm4Fg2yTeaNec) ) 
and could write program with the  XPATH for the $x evaluation statement.

```
        const [WCPub]  = await page.$x('//*[@id="details"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td');
```

But now I would need for a querySelector also a selector string. The following transfer from XPATH does not work. Can anyone tell me the correct querySelector string base on the XPATH?

```
        WCPub  = WCbookelement.querySelector('//*[@id="details"]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td');
```

I have tried that:

```
 WCbookJson.BOOKPUB  =  WCbookelement.querySelector('#"details" div > table > 
                                                     tbody > tr[3] >td').innerHTML;
```

It is the Publication field from Worldcat:

[image]
But get an error that the selector is invalid. What did I not understand correctly?

Thanks
Walter

Comment: (format questions with a [mcve] _before posting_)

Comment: AFAIK `#"details"` is not a valid selector.

Comment: `tr[3]` - you’ll probably want to use `:nth-child()` for that.

Comment: (And strictly speaking, `[@id="details"]` and `#details` aren’t the exact same thing either. It probably won’t matter for this use case, but in CSS the specificity of the attribute selector and the ID selector are different.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove the dubble quotes (`"`) around your id selector and use `:nth-child` to select the correct index of the row.

But to be honest, I think you transformed the selector from xPath to literally. You can probably also just do `#details tr:nth-child(3) > td` (depending on your html structure).

```js
var text = document.querySelector('#details > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td').innerHTML;
console.log(text);
```

```html
<div id="details">
  <div>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Row 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```